# How to convert local image path to url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am fairly new to React, and is trying to convert an local image file path to a data url or blob url that can be used in the  src.

`import image from "./img1.jpeg"` will not work for my case because the image file will only be created after some user interaction that will trigger the backend processing script.

I have an idea of creating a hidden upload field and upload the image then convert it to URL with `URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])` but I have no knowledge in doing that...

Since @quentin stated that I should convert the file path to URL in server-side code(expressjs), how can I do the conversion?

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. What do you mean by "local"? Is it (a) part of the React project source code? (b) A URL on the HTTP server hosting the built React project? (c) A file the user selects from their local disk?

Comment: @Quentin Definitely not (a) and (b), the scenario is that, I have a web where the user click on a button -> that will now triggers a python script that will generate a bunch of images -> the file path of these images will be passed back to React -> React has to display these images.

Comment: File paths are useless to client-side code. Pass a URL back instead. Then just use the URL instead of fiddling about with blobs.

Comment: Does that mean i have to convert the file paths to URL in ExpressJS code instead of returning the paths?

Comment: Yes. The client can't access the server's file system. That would be a terrible security problem.

Comment: May i know how can i convert the file path to URL in expressjs? I am fairly new to that...